# Random value always the same in recursive promise

Tags: javascript, recursion, promise

Hello I'm trying to call the function "tryToGetData" using a recursive function inside a promise so it can pass me another different random value in order to keep trying to get a "success" response, at least, until the counter is set to 5 and if not just print 'Unable to load HTML'.

But the thing is that once I get the randomvalue it looks like no matter how many times I call the function to retrieve another random value it'll always be the same value as you can see below.

First, this is my code:

```js
var a = ['unsuccessful', 'success'];
var randomValue = a[Math.floor(a.length * Math.random())];
let statuscounter= 0;

Promise.resolve(randomValue)

.then((value) => {
    console.log(value)
    return value
})
.then(function tryToGetData(status) {

  if (status !== "success" && statuscounter <= 5) {
      console.log('First attempt');

      statuscounter +=1
      return tryToGetData(randomValue)

  } else if(status !== "success" && statuscounter > 5){
      console.log('Unable to load HTML');
      return false;
  }else{
    console.log('HTML loaded, wait to load resources');
  }
})
.catch(error => reject(err));
```

This is the output if I get unsuccessful as the random value:

```
"unsuccessful"
"First attempt"
"First attempt"
"First attempt"
"First attempt"
"First attempt"
"First attempt"
"Unable to load HTML"
```

Whereas what I want is for example this:

```
"unsuccessful"
"First attempt"
//call the function again and in that case I'll get "success" as randomvalue:
"success"
"HTML loaded, wait to load resources"
```

Comment: Please could you format your code so that the indentation levels are clear.

Comment: _"no matter how many times I call the function to retrieve another random value"_ - You're never changing the value of `randomValue` O.o

Comment: Edited. Ok @Andreas, how can I change it? It's suposed to be random, right?

Comment: Get a new value from `a` before calling `tryToGetData(randomValue)`

Comment: This `a[Math.floor(a.length * Math.random())];` doesn't give you a new random number every time you reference the variable it is assigned to

Comment: Ok, Andreas, I see, now with tryToGetData(a[Math.floor(a.length * Math.random())])  works

Comment: Would you have wondered the same if you had written `const randomValue = a[Math.floor(a.length * Math.random())];`?

Comment: `.catch(error => reject(err))` looks like you are somehow using the [`Promise` constructor antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572?What-is-the-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-to-avoid-it)

Comment: yes, misspelled the error